# Is there a test runner for .NET tests that can run multi-threaded to take advantage of multi-core machines?

Tags: .net, testing, continuous-integration, gallio, xunit.net

I'm setting up CI at present using Thoughtworks Studios' Cruise, Gallio to run xunit.net fact/tests, and ncover 2 to do code-coverage.

I noticed that running the code-coverage pegs one of the four CPUs that our build-agent server has, and wondered whether there was a multi-threaded test-runner that I might use instead, to take advantage of the other 3 cores that are sat idle?  I had a quick search around, but most hits are in reference to testing multi-threaded code, not multi-threaded test running...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gallio [implements](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=355) parallel test execution.

Answer (score 1):

In NUnit you can pass a [/thread parameter](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.4) which spawns test execution in a different thread. I'd imagine it wouldn't be too much more work to have a thread pool to spawn tests from. You'd have to make darn sure you don't have dependencies in your tests.

I'd ask on either the xUnit.NET or NUnit lists. I know Charlie is working to make that part of NUnit 3.0. You can also look at [PNunit](http://pnunit.codicesoftware.com/opdownloads2/oppnunit.aspx) as an extension. There's also [an article](http://www.damonpayne.com/2008/05/09/ConcurrentUnitTestingWithXUnitNet0.aspx) with someone working towards getting xUnit.NET in multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Just yesterday i came across this post by Damon Payne:

http://www.damonpayne.com/2008/05/09/ConcurrentUnitTestingWithXUnitNet1.aspx

where he walks through writing a custom test runner for xUnit.NET that explicitly distributes test cases using the class as the unit of concurrency in order to take advantage of multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, I know that in CruiseControl.NET, you could multiple two operations run simultaneously. I would think the same would be true for Cruise.  You could have four instances of run on 1/4 of your tests each, and then stitch the results back together.  Knowing when to merge them may be difficult though.